# Best way to override custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, custom-theme, parent-child-theme

I bought a custom theme for my Magento store and want to customize it slightly.

Customizations mean that I will probably update layouts, templates, and other files that are available under *app/design/custom-theme*.

What is the best way to customize these without losing changes when a future theme update is performed? I am thinking about creating a child theme, but I am unsure if this is the best strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (afaik) is to create a child theme and make parent theme you purchased.

In these way it will inherit all properties of parent theme you purchase and easy to customize.

It will also ease upgrade theme in future.